# Reactjs multiple if className's

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following element:

```
<div className="safety-bar"></div>
```

I also have 2 classes that I want to apply to this:

- **.active** if `user.safety_score > 0`
- **.zero** if `user.safety_score == 0`

The only way I can think about doing it is:

`{ user.safety_score > 0 ? "safety-bar active" : "safety-bar zero" }`

However, If both if statements weren't a if else, I was wondering if there was any other shorthand that didn't involve creating an entire function that I could use.

Comment: You can nest ternarys.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div className="{`safety-bar ${user.safety_score > 0 ? 'active' : 'zero'}`}"></div>
```

It uses the template string syntax to append the class using a conditional operator.

Comment: This is an if/else. I was hoping there was a way to id a if/else if

Comment: IMHO, This honestly looks worse than the code in the question

Comment: @Sung Kim, I never said the code looked good. I thought the question was for code golfing the syntax.

Comment: @bryan, you can write multiple if cases with multiple conditional operators. Instead of the "else" part, just put empty string.

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I apologize if I sounded snarky . I honestly thought the original code by bryan looked `good enough`.

Comment: @SungKim No worries! Cheers. Yeah, even I would not recommend chaining conditional operators for application logic with multiple ifs. Only, here the question was about writing shorthands

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
render() {
  let safetyClass;
  if(user.safety_score > 0) {
   safetyClass = 'active'
  }

  if(user.safety_score === 0) {
   safetyClass = 'zero'
  }



  return <div className={`safety-bar ${safetyClass}`}>
}
```

Readable code is FAR better than shorthand.

Answer (score 2):

If [you want to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544056/reactjs-multiple-if-classnames/51544386#comment90056339_51544138) `if` or ternary statements, you can take advantage of `||` operator.

How it works is that when `user.safety_score` isn't found in the `flags`, it will return `undefined` and the default value of `active` will be printed for all values other than `0`.

```js
let user = {
 safety_score: 0
}

const flags = ['zero']
// prints "safety-bar zero"
console.log(`safety-bar ${flags[user.safety_score] || 'active'}`);

user.safety_score = 3;
// prints "safety-bar active"
console.log(`safety-bar ${flags[user.safety_score] || 'active'}`);
```

Honestly,

```
{ user.safety_score > 0 ? "safety-bar active" : "safety-bar zero" }
```

looks **good enough**.